# How to disable multiple touch on a UICollectionView

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad

How can I disable multiple touch on a UICollectionView ?

I want to disable the selection of two cell simultaneously.

I tried this but it doesn't work :

```
self.collectionView.multipleTouchEnabled = NO;
self.collectionView.exclusiveTouch = YES;
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could set a Boolean flag to true after ***didSelectItemAtIndexPath*** is called for the first time and return from the method if the flag is false (for the second call to the method). After you return from your displayed view, you can set your flag back to false in order to enable a single call (the first one) to the method again.

In your ***viewDidAppear*** set the flag to FALSE (no touching has been done)

Then in your ***didSelectItemAtIndexPath***

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
   if(self.flag==TRUE){
       return;
   }
   // This will set the flag to TRUE the first time the method is called
   self.flag=TRUE;
   // the rest of your code: display the view
}
```

Assuming you have already declared a flag instance variable in your class.

*** UPDATE for Swift4 code ***

```
 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
      if flag { return }

      // This will set the flag to TRUE the first time the method is called
      flag = true
      // the rest of your code: display the view
 }
```

Comment: Yes I think it's the solution.. Thank you.