# Collectionview single selection

Tags: objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, nsobject

I want to allow user to select only one cell & data will be reflected based on that. (so only one cell will be selected at a time.) but instead if I click fast with multiple finger I m able to select multiple cell at certain time.

I have done this with `didSelectItemAtIndexPath` & `didDeselectItemAtIndexPath` as well but in that case I m not able to select.

Can anyone help for this feature?

Here is the sample code that I m using:-

```
    [CustomCollection setShowsHorizontalScrollIndicator:NO];
    [CustomCollection setBounces:NO];
    [CustomCollection setAllowsMultipleSelection:NO];
    [CustomCollection setMultipleTouchEnabled:NO];

-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *identifier = @"TheCustomCell";

       CustomCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:identifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

        if (previousIndexPath.row == indexPath.row) {
    // Code for Selecttion
        [cell.tickImgView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Select_tick"]];

    }
     else{
        [cell.tickImgView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Deselect_tick"]];

}


}


-(void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        previousIndexPath = indexPath;
        [CustomCollection reloadData];
    });  
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34614815/how-to-disable-multiple-touch-on-a-uicollectionview

Comment: @ManishPathak I have tried this way but It's still selecting multiple cell.

Comment: Is it required to reload the collectionView each time you select an item.

Comment: @ManishPathak yes, it is required.

Comment: You surely don't need to reload the entire collection -- probably just the deselected and selected items.

Comment: @Caleb yes I did that initially but in that case cell does not stay selected, It get selected & deselect immediately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I have found solution.

I just made my own custom didDeselect method & handle in cellForItemAtIndexPath.

Answer (score 2):

following is my working code.

I declared `previousIndexPath` in .h like follo
below

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSIndexPath *previousIndexPath;
```

Now in .m file

```
-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *identifier = @"TheCustomCell";

    CustomCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:identifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    if ([self.previousIndexPath isEqual:indexPath]) {
        // Code for Selecttion
        [cell.tickImgView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Select_tick"]];

    }
    else{
        //Code for deselect
        [cell.tickImgView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Deselect_tick"]];

    }
    return cell;

}


-(void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    //reload collectionview data only if its not selected already 
    if (![self.previousIndexPath isEqual:indexPath])
    {
        self.previousIndexPath = indexPath;
        [collectionView reloadData];

    }

}
```

I compared indexpath directly using `isEqual:` method instead of indexPath.row and == operators.

Comment: You also removed the `dispatch_async()` call.

Comment: @Caleb is right & it is still going into If condition for cellForItemAtIndexPath & multiple selection is happening.